# How to time integrate a two variable nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a system of differential equations of the kind shown below, and I would like to know how to do a time integration for known initial conditions of variables $x$ and $y$:

$$\ddot{x}+\dot{x}\dot{y} +y = f(t)$$
$$\ddot{x}+\dot{x} +x  +y = 0$$

where $f$ is a known function of time. I have ignored the parameters for each addend.

I have experience integrating "simple" ODEs, but here I do not know how to separate the variables and/or deal with $\dot{x}\dot{y}$.

Thank you!

Comment: You get $(x+x')+x'(x'+x''+x''')=-f(t)$ not easy to integrate

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question due to lack of context.